# Resource already exists on disk: '/myproject/bin/META-INF/persistence.xml'

Tags: eclipse, spring, jpa, gradle, datanucleus

In Eclipse 4.4 and 4.5, after a restart or a project clean, I get the following error: `The project was not built due to "Resource already exists on disk: '/myproject/bin/META-INF/persistence.xml'."` I'm using Datanucleus 4.1.1 and Eclipse DataNucleus Enhancer plugin 4.0. I don't have that file on my sources, as I'm relying on JPA annotations.

Sometimes I got a very similar error `The project was not built due to "Resource already exists on disk: '/myproject/bin/META-INF/logback.xml'."`. And even with `/myproject/bin/.gitkeep`.

The workaround to fix this is to delete the `/bin` subfolder, refresh the project and rebuild. But this is becoming annoying and I would need a more permanent and automated solution.

The project is using Gradle and it was imported in Eclipse as a Gradle project. I also installed Gradle IDE plugin.

Comment: Just guessing here, but a lot of Eclipse problems seems to get fixed by deleting the project, then deleting the .project and .classpath file... And reimporting the project...

Comment: @Danielson, I already did this ... quite a few times ...

Comment: @NeilStockton, no, you don't. If you're using Spring and more specifically `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`, this scans a given set of packages and discovers the JPA entities.

Comment: DataNucleus Enhancer plugin can discover the classes itself. Probably behind the scenes, it generates `persistence.xml`, but you don't have to write it yourself.

Comment: Still, I don't have the file and it works :).

Comment: Having the same issue, but just on a straight eclipse-java-maven project